# Is there a way to let multiple users or a role upload photos to one single gallery in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, photo-gallery, drupal-roles

Is there a way to let multiple users or a role upload photos to one single gallery in drupal 7?

The users can upload images to their own (self created) gallery at this moment, but I want them to be able to upload images in to a single general gallery too.

This is about a website for a small group (family) where every user is trusted.Its a kind of intranet.

All the content is added by the users them selfes, they can all make photo gallery's and add photo's to ther own gallery's.

but now I want them to be able to upload images in to a single general gallery too.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details?!

Comment: From the drupal-7 tag: *Rather than using this tag, consider posting your question directly on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/.* You might get more help in a dedicated community.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely different depending on how you are doing the gallery.

The most common solution would be to simply create a content type with a file upload, then give permissions to create that content type for all the roles you want to be able to upload. Then the gallery itself would be a view -- there are many views plugins to make this happen if you don't want to style it up yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your tip! I wil try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Although the [Organic Groups module](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) can get a little involved, it's designed for grouping users with Group roles and permissions to specific nodes. Additionally, it has field access, which can limit certain roles to fields within those nodes rather than owning the whole node.